# PYSPARK - Parallelize read json with multiple keys with the same metadata

Tags: python, json, pyspark, struct

i'm having trouble trying to read a json just like below:

```
{
  "cats":{
    "1":{
      "name":"meow",
      "favorite_food":"milk"
    },
    "2":{
      "name":"honey",
      "favorite_food":"fish"
    },
    "3":{
      "name":"cutie",
      "favorite_food":"milk"
    },
    "4":{
      "name":"puss",
      "favorite_food":"chicken"
    },
    "n"......
  }
}
```

I want to output a table_cats like this:

| name | favorite_food |
| --- | --- |
| meow | milk |
| honey | fish |

the problem that i'm having is that I can have multiple "ids" and multiple keys inside each id (like favorite_toy, favorite_owner, etc) - i need to read this dynamic json.
any ideas?

I was trying reading, exploding and in some way unpivoting the output, but it wasn't practical at all since i can have thousands of columns like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your JSON into Python and convert the dictionary under `"cats"` to a list of records:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

data = """{
  "cats":{
    "1":{
      "name":"meow",
      "favorite_food":"milk"
    },
    "2":{
      "name":"honey",
      "favorite_food":"fish"
    },
    "3":{
      "name":"cutie",
      "favorite_food":"milk"
    },
    "4":{
      "name":"puss",
      "favorite_food":"chicken"
    }
  }
}"""

json_data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame([v for k, v in json_data["cats"].items()])
```

Result:

```
    name favorite_food
0   meow          milk
1  honey          fish
2  cutie          milk
3   puss       chicken
```

Comment: hey @foglerit, thanks for the answer!

I can see that it works, but since it's a really big data with multiple keys in my json + i'm working with pyspark i'd rather not use python.
do you know any way to replicate this in pyspark?

Comment: If your data are in one very large file, this will not work. But if they are in many files and you are using PySpark to parallelize the loading, then you may be able to pre-process the data in Python at the nodes. You should open another question focusing on the parallelization task.

Comment: title edited to make the issue clearer

Answer (score 0):

read JSON files in spark using this spark.read.json(), but use the multiLine option as a single JSON is spread across multiple lines.

```
spark.read.option(multiline=True).json(path)
```